# Чи є відповідник до слова "худі"?

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова

Зараз серед модного та зручного одягу популярними є **худі**. Ця назва є повсюди, наприклад, [тут](https://skidochnik.com.ua/uk/lvov/razdel/genskie-kofty-i-pulovery/marker/jenskie-hudi). Однак цікавить чи є український відповідник до цього слова?

Інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Худі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%96) – це неологізм, запозичений з англійської мови і пов’язаний з видом одягу:

> **Ху́ді** (від англ. hood — «каптур») — светр (кофта) з м'якого бавовняного трикотажу, з каптуром. Характерні елементи — велика накладна кишеня спереду і шнурки для затягування каптура, також може мати вертикальну блискавку по центру, схожу як у куртках.

В словниках  на даний момент немає зафіксованого  українського відповідника цього слова, тому можемо використовувати описові сполуки на позначення цієї кофти. Також знайшла цікаві варіанти перекладу на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/khudi): **бобка, кенгуринка, каптурник, каптурка, байка, кофта з відлогою, гуді, кенгуру.**